# Should I balance data set for survival random forest?

Tags: survival, random-forest, unbalanced-classes

Should I balance data set for survival random forest?  By subsampling I will loose information in data set. However I would do that in RF for classification. Should it be done also in case of survival analysis? I am not sure whether there is a conceptual difference.

Comment: What do you mean by survival random forest?

Comment: a random forest with survival object as response variable. It is trained with package randomForestSRC in R.

Comment: Don't balance, in neither case. [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't balance, in neither case. [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)

(Converted from [a comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/479233/should-i-balance-data-set-for-survival-random-forest#comment884775_479233). For my rationale, [see here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5000/1352). On short answers, [see here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352). Better and longer answers are always welcome.)